# Predefined templates in database

Tags: sql, t-sql

On a database I have the tables:

```
USERS
Id
Name

PLAN_TYPES
Id
Name

PLANS
Id
PlanTypeId
UserId
Name

ACTIONS
Id
PlanId
TakeActionTime
Description
```

After a Plan is created for a User an Action is periodically added to that plan by the application ...

In same cases instead of creating the plan in real time there will be a plan template with its type and actions predefined.

What is the best way to to include the template in the database scheme?

Comment: Probably Triggers are your best bet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself correctly. A plan can be generated in Real Time by the application or use a Template which is created by Users.

Comment: So how do you plan to distinguish between a template plan and an actual plan?

Comment: Show sample records and data so we don't misunderstand you.

Comment: When a Plan is first created for a User it is empty. Then there are two options: 1 - The plan actions are added daily by the application using business rules. 2 - When the plan is created it is defined a source of predefined actions (template) that was created by some user for their clients. Those predefined actions fill the plan daily.

Comment: That last comment just made this question more confusing. However I think my answer still stands.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, my fault ... I see different ways of doing this so I still don't have a clear definition.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a `bit` column to the `plans` table indicating it's a template plan, and when the user wants to activate it have a stored procedure copy it to new records.
This way each users can define it's own templates, and "activate" them as real plans whenever they want. You can also have "system defined" templates, where the bit column would show it's a template but the `userId` column will be null, so every user will be able to create active plans from them.

So your `plans` table ends up looking like this:

```
PLANS
Id
PlanTypeId
UserId (nullable)
Name
IsTemplate (bit, you might want to set default to 1 or 0 here)
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems a viable option ... I am also adding AuthorId which is not null when the template is created by a user and null when the template is created by the system. I am just checking a few more things.